# asp.net core publish cause ERROR_FILE_IN_USE

Tags: asp.net

I deploy using VS2015 by publish to production share folder, but if the site is running the publish script will stop at ERROR_FILE_IN_USE because of asp.net Core is using an executable as web server.

how do i auto stop the site before publish and start the site after publish?
i know the file `app_offline.htm` will cause the site stop but i dont want to place the file every time publish.

i tried add True in my .pubxml but got another error. `ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`

or how do I use pre/post script to handle the app_offline.htm file?